# Why I am seeing 'Not enough data' in 'Events' report for my app in facebook analytics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

I have suddenly started getting 'Not enough data' as the App install source ad / adset when I see an app event report and try to find the source adset for the app event.

It is showing even when I have more than 2000 count for that event. Not enough data is only shown when you have only fewer events.

I last checked for Mar month on Apr 2nd when it was showing me the app install source adset for my events perfectly. But, when I check the data for March now, it does not show me the app install source data for the custom events.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail - what report are you looking at when you see this? What are the specific settings for the report (e.g. if Breakdowns, what parameters are you using to breakdown?)

Comment: @Jyoti did you find a solution? We have an app with hundreds of thousands of unique users and hundreds of thousands of events, but the Age and Gender view still shows "Not enough data" which obviously doesn't make sense.